# How to count number of times a “group” had more than 1 value in another field

Tags: sql, mysql

My unique SQL use case is as follows:

I have userId, isCondition, timestamp

I want number times all results per userId has timestamp always containing a starting substring and isCondition value has more than 1 distinct value amongst those results

Example:

UserID1, timestamp*, 0

UserID1, timestamp*, 1

UserID2, timestamp*, 0

UserID2, timestamp*, 0

Returns 1 because only 1 group of results for userID1 had isCondition with multiple distinct values. Had the 3rd or 4th row had distinct values for column 3, the result would have been 2 indicating 2 users demonstrating distinct values for column 3 for the same global timestamp substring value

Sample DB creation:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  user varchar(255),
  timestp varchar(255),
  isCond int
);
INSERT INTO test (user, timestp, isCond) VALUES ("user1", "2024-02-08-11", 0);
INSERT INTO test (user, timestp, isCond) VALUES ("user1", "2024-02-08-12", 1);
INSERT INTO test (user, timestp, isCond) VALUES ("user2", "2024-02-08-13", 0);
INSERT INTO test (user, timestp, isCond) VALUES ("user2", "2024-02-08-12", 0);
```

I found that query outputs a row with count per instance and I just need to get the count of the number of row this outputs:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT isCond) AS counti FROM test 
WHERE timestp like "2024-02-08%"
GROUP BY user HAVING counti=2;
```

Expected output = 2

Comment: Can you also post your expected result from sample data. That would clarify better

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM tabl 
GROUP BY userId, isCondition, timestamp 
HAVING `count`> 1;
```

Replace the tabl with your table

Answer (score 0):

Found that this does the trick

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT isCond) AS counti FROM test 
WHERE timestp like "2024-02-08%"
GROUP BY user HAVING counti>1) as myq;
```